# Display modal pop up before user clicks on menu items Javascript native

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup, dom-events, confirm

I need to put a modal in native Javascript to tell the user "You are about to leave the sales page". That will happen if the user click on the menu items that are in a page-header class. So if the user wants to click in the menu links, the modal will appears and if the user accepts the stay, will stay, if not he will leave in the link he clicked.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("page-header");
    if(x == true){
        return "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?\nAll unsaved changes will be lost.";
    }
}
```

```
<ul class="page-header">
<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your question is missing

Comment: yes @AKZhang i cant post it..i need to keep a user in a page and if the user want to click on the menu items that are in class page-header i need to ask him if he wants to leave

Comment: I thought you got the solution already.. refer this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload Or do you mean changing the native to desired modal?

Comment: @AKZhang yes, i saw that. I need to put fully in javascript native, on a js file. And need to only set the modal (not alert sorry) if the user click on the menu items that are in class page-header

Comment: @DanArg, yes you do describe what you want to get done but not describing where you are stuck/having a problem and without actually taking a look at your code it is going to be hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check here, may be you are looking for this.
[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/W3A6f6PE0adR1kt5VjkR?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#backPage').on('click',function(){
      var userConfirmation = confirm("Your data may be lost");
      if(userConfirmation){
        return window.location.href="index.html";
      }else
        return false;
    });
 });
```